# how to add color to ttk module widgets?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

How to add bg color to widgets in ttk module?, The bellow isn't giving me the needed results.
I tried the usual method as Tkinter module. But it didn't work.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import sqlite3

db_obj = sqlite3.connect("contact.db")
def count_index():
    cur = db_obj.cursor()
    count = cur.execute("select count(index) from contacts;")
    rowcount = cur.fetchone()[0]
    return rowcount

def enter(event=None):
    x=e1.get()
    y=e2.get()
    ci=count_index()+1
    db_obj.execute("insert into contacts(index, name, number) 
values(?,?,?);",(ci,x,y))
    db_obj.commit()


fx =Frame(bg="LightCyan2")
bt=Button(fx)
fr.pack(expand=YES)
l1=Label(fx, text="Enter name", bg="LightCyan2").grid(row=1,column=1)
l2=Label(fx, text="Enter number", bg="LightCyan2").grid(row=2,column=1)
e1=Entry(fx)
e2=Entry(fx)
e1.grid(row=1,column=2)
e2.grid(row=2,column=2)
e1.focus()
e2.focus()
bt.config(text="ENTER",command=enter)
bt.grid(row=3,column=2)
bt.bind('<Return>',enter)

fx.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to `StackOverflow`, please be a bit more specific when asking question: *What have you tried so far with code example?* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use style a style object to add color to widgets.
Define the style object seperatly and the use the name of the style in your labels to get the required style.

```
s1 = Style()
s1.configure('My.Frame', background='LightCyan2')
```

Modified code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import sqlite3

db_obj = sqlite3.connect("contact.db")
def count_index():
    cur = db_obj.cursor()
    count = cur.execute("select count(index) from contacts;")
    rowcount = cur.fetchone()[0]
    return rowcount

def enter(event=None):
    x=e1.get()
    y=e2.get()
    ci=count_index()+1
    conx.execute("insert into words(index, name, number) values(?,?,?);",(ci,x,y))
   conx.commit()


s1 = Style()
s1.configure('My.Frame', background='LightCyan2')

s2=Style()
s2.configure('My.Label', background='LightCyan2')

fx =Frame(style='My.Frame')
bt=Button(fx)
fx.pack(expand=YES)
l1=Label(fx, text="Enter word", style='My.Label').grid(row=1,column=1)
l2=Label(fx, text="Enter meaning", style='My.Label').grid(row=2,column=1)
e1=Entry(fx)
e2=Entry(fx)
e1.grid(row=1,column=2)
e2.grid(row=2,column=2)
e1.focus()
e2.focus()
bt.config(text="ENTER",command=enter)
bt.grid(row=3,column=2)
bt.bind('<Return>',enter)

fx.mainloop()
```

I guess this solves your problem, Though I am not sure if this is what you meant to ask.

Comment: yes, Hille is right, maybe you should point out the exact code lines which made the problem instead of the entire code.

Comment: I will do that next time, Thank you so much for your help.